# exec.Command not working in golang for multiple bash commands

Tags: bash, macos, shell, go, command

I need to source a file and get the variables from the file using golang. I am doing as can be seen below:

```
cmd1 := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source fileName|echo $INFO")
out, err := cmd1.Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
}
fmt.Printf("combined out:\n%s\n", string(out))
```

If I execute this command in terminal on macos i see the information i need. But if I execute this command within go, I get nothing in the output.
I am new to go. Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you piping something into `echo`? If `INFO` is defined in the sourced file, it's not going to be echo'ed from this command unless it was already assigned in the parent shell.

Comment: @JimB, I changed the command above to `cmd1 := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "fileName", "echo $INFO")` this is not giving any output either.

Comment: cmd1 := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source fileName; echo $INFO") helped. Thanks @JimB

$INFO is defined and exported in the fileName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of piping the command, I needed to do the below:

```
cmd1 := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source fileName; echo $INFO")
```